# URL doesn't retract on iPhone

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, iphone

I'm working on a website: [www.shareone.dk](http://www.shareone.dk)
But when i scroll down the site on iPhone, the top-bar containing the URL doesn't retract upwards, like it does on other websites. Which results in me not being able to double click the top-bar/clock to go back to the top of the site. I think it might be an issue with my HTML, CSS og jQuery. Any ideas? The issue is also on Android, but not as problematic as I'm not able to double click the top, to get back to the top of the site on Android browser.

Comment: Please provide relevant code, then we can help you. It sounds like you have a "sticky" header, that is always at the top of the screen, nevermind where you scroll, correct?

Comment: There is no sticky header. I don't know which code to provide you. I had hoped for a comment like "Oh, you can't use overflow: hidden, that will cause that well-known issue".

Comment: You're asking on the wrong site if you want that help, see here [mcve]

Comment: Thanks - i will try another website.